# How do I express a trait bound of a supertrait's associated type without repeating the trait bound on each method?

Tags: generics, types, error-handling, rust, traits

Here's the code I would like to compile:

```
struct Error {}

trait Foo {
    type FooError;
    fn fallible_function() -> Result<(), Self::FooError>;
}

trait SubFoo: Foo
where
    Error: From<<Self as Foo>::FooError>,
{
}

fn some_function<T: SubFoo>(object: T) {}
```

Unfortunately, it won't compile without repeating the `From` trait bound under `some_function`, like this:

```
fn some_function<T: SubFoo>(object: T)
where
    Error: From<<T as Foo>::FooError>,
{
}
```

That defeats the point though, as the point of `SubFoo` is to reduce the boilerplate on the many points where its fully described supertraits would be used (you can imagine this is a lot more bulky in my real code than in this simplified snippet). I'm aware the reason why this doesn't work is [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671), which appears to be a little bit stuck in limbo (with the possible implication that nothing you could ever express here is inexpressible with normal trait bounds, outside a `where` clause?)

Since the above is a no-go until that issue gets closed, I'm looking for alternative solutions to my problem. Pulling the `associated_type_bounds` unstable feature, at least I'm able to express a similar constraint:

```
#![feature(associated_type_bounds)]

struct Error {}

trait Foo {
    type FooError;
    fn fallible_function() -> Result<(), Self::FooError>;
}

trait SubFoo: Foo<FooError: Into<Error>> {}
```

This is **almost** fine (and to be fair, looks a lot more elegant than the `where` clause before). However, it won't cut it for two reasons:

- Where `From<A> for B` implies `Into<B> from A`, the reverse is not true.
- The `?` operator requires `From<FooError> for Error`

I can't think of a way to encode the `From<FooError> for Error` requirement in the supertrait bound without using a `where` clause. Am I missing a key bit of syntax here, or am I out of luck?

I can't do this:

```
trait Foo
where
    Error: From<Self::FooError>,
{
    type FooError;
    fn fallible_function() -> Result<(), Self::FooError>;
}
```

In my real code, this would break encapsulation (the module where Foo lives has no reason to see the top level Error struct).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very well-researched question. I got a few ideas what to try while reading this, but you already tried all of them yourself.